# What is this dashed box and how can I turn it off?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, objects

I was just getting back into using Blender a few days ago and I must have hit a couple of buttons. But now I cannot get these dashed lines to go away. Does anybody know how I can make them go away?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> which enables texture space display and translates/grabs it.

You can disable *Texture space display* in *Properties > Object > Display*:

[image]

In case you accidentally translated it, you may want to set it back to `0,0,0` in *Properties > Object data > Texture space* and re-enable *Auto texture space*:

[image]

Comment: I recently disabled the keyboard shortcut for this feature in the user preferences, now it no longer pesters me when I mistakenly press that shortcut when I am trying to Triangulate(Ctrl-t).