# Remove a dotted cage?

Tags: mesh

Someone knows what it is that dotted cage, what it serves but especially how to remove it?
[image: Doted Cage]

Comment: I'd need to see the .blend. The only cage like that I remember is from curve handles, when you twist them, with meshes, I'd have to have a closer look.
In the meanwhile check the physics tab if something is activated there.

Comment: it might be the Texture Space: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14120/what-is-this-dashed-box-and-how-can-i-turn-it-off/14121

Comment: Thank you @moonboots ! it was a texture space ;) I was afraid that it adds elements to my models for my video game ^^ '